# Pygame - detect if music is played and stop it

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

Currently my code looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from pygame import mixer

class Application(Frame):
    def play_sound(self):
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load('F:\Bibliothek\Musik\ABGENOMMEN.mp3')
        mixer.music.play()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.sound1 = Button(self, height = 10, width = 27)
        self.sound1["text"] = "sound1"
        self.sound1["fg"]   = "green"
        self.sound1["command"] = self.play_sound
        self.sound1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.sound2 = Button(self, height = 10, width = 27)
        self.sound2["text"] = "sound2"
        self.sound2["fg"]   = "green"
        self.sound2["command"] = self.play_sound
        self.sound2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.QUIT = Button(self, height = 10, width = 27)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit
        self.QUIT.grid(row=2, column=3)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()        

root = Tk()
#root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.geometry("800x480")
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

If I press a button it will play music. Now I want that, if I press a button and there is music currently playing, I want to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an attribute in your class, (in the `__init__ constructor`)  like

```
self.sound_running = False
```

Then pass it to True in your `play_sound` method when you begin to play the sound, after checking it's not already set to True, if so, you can call :

```
mixer.music.stop()
```

or 
    mixer.music.fadeout(1000) # time in millisecond

```
self.sound_running = False # and reset attribute to False
```

Also, you should init the mixer once (in the constructor too)

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.pack()
    self.is_running = False
    mixer.init()        
    self.createWidgets()

def play_sound(self):
    if self.is_running:
        mixer.music.fadeout(1000)
        self.is_running = False
    else:
        self.is_running = True
        mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
        mixer.music.play()
```

The last lines should be:

```
app = Application(master=root)
root.mainloop()
```

(your way is throwing an error when you close it)

And have fun with your rhythm box !